# Replace double quotes in a json string using php

Tags: php, json, validation

I need to convert a JSON string in array using PHP, but I need to escape double quotes.

```
$string = '["label":"Name","type":"text","placeholder":"Mario","name":"name",*],
["label":"Email","type":"email","placeholder":"mail@example.com","name":"email",*],
["label":"Message","type":"textarea","value":"In this box you can insert a <a href="#" target="_blank">link</a>"]';
$jsonify = strip_tags($string,"<a>");
$jsonify = str_replace('*','"required":"required"',$jsonify);
$jsonify = str_replace('[','{',str_replace(']','}',$jsonify));
$jsonify = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"),"",$jsonify);
$jsonify = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $jsonify);
$jsonify = '['.jsonify.']';
echo $jsonify;

// OUTPUT IS:
[{"label":"Name","type":"text","placeholder":"Mario","name":"name","required":"required"}, {"label":"Email","type":"email","placeholder":"mail@example.com","name":"email","required":"required"}, {"label":"Message","type":"textarea","value":"In this box you can insert a <a href="#" target="_blank">link</a>"}]

// BUT IS NOT JSON VALID. IT SHOULD BE THIS:
[{"label":"Name","type":"text","placeholder":"Mario","name":"name","required":"required"}, {"label":"Email","type":"email","placeholder":"mail@example.com","name":"email","required":"required"}, {"label":"Message","type":"textarea","value":"In this box you can insert a <a href=\"#\" target=\"_blank\">link</a>"}]
```

How can I obtain a valid JSON string?

Comment: uhhhhhhhhmmmmm `json_encode`?

Comment: I have used json_encode but I get this:

`"[\"label\":\"Name\",\"type\":\"text\",\"placeholder\":\"Mario\",\"name\":\"name\",*],\n[\"label\":\"Email\",\"type\":\"email\",\"placeholder\":\"mail@example.com\",\"name\":\"email\",*],\n[\"label\":\"Message\",\"type\":\"textarea\",\"value\":\"In this box you can insert a link<\/a>\"]"`

Comment: Is it in your control to modify what `$string` starts as?

Comment: No, I get the strings as I posted

Comment: I thought of a solution, but I do not know how to write it:
I could replace all **="any_content"** with **=\"any_content\"**

Comment: Great! Adding this line I obtain a JSON valid string `$jsonify = preg_replace('/="([^\"]*)"/', '=\\"$1\\"', $jsonify);`

Answer (score 0):

your string is not a json valid

this is a `$string` json valid

```
  [
    {
        "label": "Name",
        "type": "text",
        "placeholder": "Mario",
        "name": "name"
    },
    {
        "label": "Email",
        "type": "email",
        "placeholder": "mail@example.com",
        "name": "email"
    },
    {
        "label": "Message",
        "type": "textarea",
        "value": "In this box you can insert a <a href='#' target='_blank'>link</a>"
    }
]
```

test this,and remove other code `strip_tags,Str_replace,preg_replace`

```
echo json_encode($string);
```

Comment: I have used json_encode but I obtain a not valid JSON string

Comment: your string is not a valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

You get a valid json file by simply passing your array/string to json_encode like this :

```
$array = array(
    array("label" => "Name", "type" => "text", "placeholder" => "Mario", "name" => "name"),
    array("label" => "Email", "type" => "email", "placeholder" => "mail@example.com", "name" => "email"),
    array("label" => "Message", "type" => "textarea", "value" => "In this box you can insert a <a href='#' target='_blank'>link</a>")
);

$json = json_encode($array);
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: I have used json_encode but I obtain a not valid JSON string

Comment: I get the strings as I posted, I need to convert in a valid JSON string to decode it at a later time